# What are the steps before computing time series regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, econometrics

I'm working on my thesis and I want to analyse what is influencing housing prices over time. I have 14 time series including economic and demographic data. The data have quarterly frequency and covers 9 years (36 observations for each variable). Based on one paper I want to perform regression using OLS. I'm using Eviews software.

**My question is - what steps I have to take before starting with regression?**

My plan was: 
1) Test stationarity of TS using ADF model - non-stationarity resolve taking 1st or second differences or using ln 
2) Test causality with Granger causality test 
3) Perform the regression analysis using OLS - then test residuals, model fit etc.

Are there some other things I should to first? For example do some seasonal adjustments before I start with ADF test?

I know this question might sound silly but this is my first econometric model and I'm very inexperienced - I have some theoretical background, but I do't have any systematical idea, how to organize the steps and I'm worried about forgetting something important.